# Derivative with respect of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, derivatives

i have a function of two variables:

> $f(\theta,\phi) = \theta \sin(\phi)$

and i have to differentiate $f(\theta,\phi)$ with respect to:

> $1 - 0.5\theta^2$

That is:
$$\frac{df(\theta,\phi)}{d(1 - 0.5\theta^2)}$$

i am quite clueless on how to do that.
if you have any suggestion and maybe some reference it would be very nice.

thank you

Comment: That's pretty terrible, notationally -it's just the wrong way to write it, but I think I know what is meant.

Comment: what would have been the correct notation..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac{df(\theta,\phi)}{d(1 - 0.5\theta^2)}
 &= \frac{d(\theta \sin(\phi))}{d(1-0.5 \theta^2)} \\
 &= \frac{d(\theta \sin(\phi))}{d\theta} \frac{d\theta}{d(1-0.5 \theta^2)} \\
 &= \left(\frac{d(\theta \sin(\phi))}{d\theta}\right) \left(\frac{d(1-0.5 \theta^2)}{d\theta}\right)^{-1} \\
 &= \left(\sin(\phi) + \theta \cos(\phi)\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}\right) \left(- \theta\right)^{-1} \\
 &= -\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\theta} - \cos(\phi)\frac{d\phi}{d\theta} \\
 \end{align}$$

Comment: I start to get a headache. Is it even meaningful to define $d\phi/d\theta$ for independent variables $\phi$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Is it even meaningful to call variables "independent"?

Comment: Sure, they just happen to be stuffed in one bag $x=(\theta,\phi)$. If there would be a dependence, one would reduce the $f$ manifold to a 1d submanifold.

Comment: maybe it can be helpful saying that θ and ϕ are the two spherical angular coordinates, therefore they are two "independent variables" ( i am an engeneer so i might lack some correct terminology ). i think therefore that dϕdθ should vanish...

Comment: I think this approach is implicitly picking a curve, along that curve one has a relationship between both variables, and along that curve the derivative is having that value.

Comment: i might have found something helpful: http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~jdg/AECHAIN.PDF     you might have a look at the first section of the PDF. According to what i found if we define u=1−0.5θ2 then ϕ will not depend on u

Answer (score 1):

Try using the chain rule (also in somewhat sloppy notation):
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} f(x)}{\mathrm{d} g(x)}=\frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} x}\cdot \Big(\frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} x}\Big)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

This might be a better way to think about it. Let's introduce a new variable $u$, where

\begin{equation}
u = 1 - 0.5 \theta^2 .
\end{equation}

I'm going to assume that you want the partial derivative with respect to u, and not the total derivative. We then have

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial u},
\end{equation}

where $\phi$ is left out because it is not a function of u. We now compute both derivatives.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = sin\phi
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial u} = \frac{1}{\partial u / \partial \theta} = - \frac{1}{\theta}
\end{equation}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = - \frac{sin \phi}{\theta}
\end{equation}

Comment: I am not sure if this chain rule is correct for partial derivatives. I used a different version. How to check the results?

Comment: this derivation recovers the one given by DanielV if the term dϕdθ is identically zero. anyway i'm not sure which one is correct...any idea on how to check these results?

Answer (score 0):

Giving that term a name
$$
u = 1 - \frac{1}{2} \theta^2 \Rightarrow \\
\theta = \sqrt{2(1-u)}
$$

and transforming variables from $(\theta, \phi)$ to $(u,\phi)$ for the function
$$
f(\theta, \phi) = \theta \sin \phi = \sqrt{2(1-u)} \sin \phi = f(u, \phi)
$$
then

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}
&= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial u}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \phi}
\\
&= \frac{-u}{\sqrt{2(1-u)}} \sin\phi + \sqrt{2(1-u)} \cos \phi \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Note that I had a different version in the first run, which I found not that bad either. The variation in the answers is interesting.